# Select all value starts with 52 in json

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to be able to extract all values from json array in snowflake starts with 52 or 44 and place them into different column.

I have this json formats for example:

{ 520526;15;3;{"4":{"5":150,"6":230}} 520523;15;3;{"3":{"5":150,"6":150}} }

{ 520523;15;2;{"3":{"5":150,"6":190}} 860002;15;0;{"2":{"5":150,"6":150}} }

I want this:

| First Pick | Second Pick |
| --- | --- |
| 520526 | 520523 |
| 520523 |  |

all values starts with 52 or 44

```
    select json 
,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json, '0') as first_pick
//, left(json ,6) as first_pick
//, regexp_replace(json ,',','\n') as test
from x
where date='2023-07-08' 
and json LIKE '52%' or '44%'
```

Comment: Please share your SQL code of current you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '0') LIKE '52%' THEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '0')
    WHEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '1') LIKE '52%' THEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '1')
    ELSE NULL
  END AS first_pick,
  CASE
    WHEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '0') LIKE '44%' THEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '0')
    WHEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '1') LIKE '44%' THEN JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_data, '1')
    ELSE NULL
  END AS second_pick
FROM
  my_table;
```

Comment: I receive error: Error parsing JSON: invalid character outside of a string: ';', pos 7   :(

Comment: @БилянаМитова the issue is in your json data... this `{ 520526;15;3;{"4":{"5":150,"6":230}} 520523;15;3;{"3":{"5":150,"6":150}} }` isn't valid json. it is more like another format... the following is json `{
  "data": [
    {
      "value1": 520526,
      "value2": 15,
      "value3": 3,
      "nestedData": {
        "4": {
          "5": 150,
          "6": 230
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "value1": 520523,
      "value2": 15,
      "value3": 3,
      "nestedData": {
        "3": {
          "5": 150,
          "6": 150
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: you are right! I will check and my team will update the format. thanks :)